# Dart unable to parse JSON from string to int

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to parse a JSON value from string to int but got stuck :(
The code below shows a HTTP get request and retrieving a JSON object in which I want to obtain the 'reps' value in Integer.

```
var response = await httpClient.get(url, headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'X-API-Key': apikey
        });
        print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
        print('Response body: ${response.body}');
        var res = json.decode(response.body);
        String repStr = res['reps'];
        print(repStr);
        int repInt = int.parse(repStr);
```

The debug console shows the following error on the line

> String repStr = res['reps'];

```
E/flutter ( 8562): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Comment: res['reps'] is int already. change to this: int repStr = res['reps'];

Comment: which type of value you send from server then when you decode json, you will have that type, not every thing is String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception explains, the value res['reps'] is already an integer you don't need to parse it.

```
 int repStr = res['reps'];
```